# Google Drive SDK Upload file from the browser via JS

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

The official documentation of v3 does not have an example of file upload (image) to drive.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads

So I have the code to create a folder, and I need to upload file to this folder.

```
function createFolder(){
      var parentId = '';//some parentId of a folder under which to create the new folder
      var fileMetadata = {
        'name' : 'New Folder',
        'mimeType' : 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        'parents': [ROOT_FOLDER]
      };
        gapi.client.drive.files.create({
          resource: fileMetadata,
        }).then(function(response) {
          switch(response.status){
            case 200:
              var file = response.result;
              console.log('Created Folder Id: ', file);
              break;
            default:
              console.log('Error creating the folder, '+response);
              break;
            }
        });
      }
```

Can you please post an example of how to upload a file to a directory in drive API v3?
Thanks

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can I ask you about the result when you run the current script? If error occurs, please show it. It will help users think of about your issue and solution.

Comment: @tanaike the result in this case is the folder info that was created successfully. With the folder if. Now I need to upload image to the created folder. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. From the information of your reply, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to upload a file to the specific folder using Drive API.
- When your script in your question is run, new folder is created.

  - Namely, you can already use Drive API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this sample script? Unfortunately, in my environment, the files couldn't be uploaded using `gapi.client.drive.files.create()` while a new file and new folder can be created. I thought that this might be the specification. So I used the following script as a workaround. I think that there are several solutions for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

#### Sample script:

```
let file = document.getElementsByName('upFile')[0].files[0]; // file

var metadata = {
    name: file.name,
    mimeType: file.type,
    parents: ['### folderId ###'], // Please set folderId here.
};
var form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], {type: 'application/json'}));
form.append('file', file);
fetch('https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + gapi.auth.getToken().access_token}),
  body: form
}).then((res) => {
  return res.json();
}).then(function(val) {
  console.log(val);
});
```

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that the file is inputted by `<input type="file" name='upFile'>`.
- In this sample script, the file with the size less than 5 MB can be uploaded. If you want to upload a large file more than 5 MB, please use the resumable upload. From your question, I thought that the image file might be less than 5 MB. So I proposed this script.

#### References:

- [create method of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)
- [Uploading Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)

Comment: +1 thank you! just a small question, I want now to run img src using with the file id that was created, the folder is not shared, is it possible somehow to pass the client id to the img src path and display the image?

Comment: I will need to access this file from the serverside as well.

Comment: @Shazam About your new question, you want to use the uploaded file without sharing. Under this condition, you want to make users use the uploaded file. If my understanding is correct, the file is required to be shared. And I cannot understand about ``I will need to access this file from the serverside as well.``. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: Let me simplify my question. forget about the server side. I want my app to do img src for the upload image. possible?
Thanks!

Comment: @Shazam Thank you for quick reply. In that case, the file is required to be publicly shared. After the file was uploaded, please create the permission using [Permissions: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create). If this was not what you want, I apologize.

Comment: @Shazam As an additional information, when the file is uploaded, it directly requested to the endpoint. But the creation of permission to the uploaded file can use ``gapi.client.drive.permissions.create(object)``.

Comment: what is the `object` in `gapi.client.drive.permissions.create(object)`, is this the file creation result? thanks

Comment: @Shazam I'm really sorry for my incomplete comment. A sample object is ``{fileId: val.id, role: 'reader', type: 'anyone'}``. I think that ``role: 'reader'`` and ``type: 'anyone'`` are suitable for your situation.